# How to prove Gaussian integral in normal distribution can be scaled to a standard curve?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

If I want to solve the gaussian integral for normal distribution problems I only need to scale it to a standard normal distribution curve and consult a table. I want to know why this is valid (the fact that it can be scaled to a standard curve). I want to know why the integral only depends on how many standard deviations I depart from the mean.

My textbook just says "using a result of calculus this can be proven", but I don't seem to find the proof anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Details depend on how the general normal is defined. Let us suppose that we define it as follows. We say that $X$ has normal distribution with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ if $X$ has probability density function
$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\,\sigma}e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}.$$
We want to find $\Pr(X\le x)$. This is given by 
$$\Pr(X\le x)=\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\,\sigma}e^{-(t-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}\,dt.\tag{1}$$
Make the substitution $z=\frac{t-\mu}{\sigma}$. Then $dt=\sigma\,dz$. As $t$ ranges from $-\infty$ to $x$, $z$ ranges from $-\infty$ to $(x-\mu)/\sigma$. Substituting in the integral (1), we get
$$\Pr(X\le x)=\int_{-\infty}^{(x-\mu)/\sigma} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}\,dz.$$

Comment: You are welcome. It really is, as your book said, just calculus, specifically integration by substitution.

Comment: but the top limit of the last integral is not what you plug in in the standardized function when you solve these types of problems. Whats up with that? Thanks.

Comment: I guess what I plugged in the typical questions (like psi() ) doesn't really correspond to the upper limit of the integral and was just some obscure shortcut. The method I was taught was to plug in the number of standard deviations departed from the mean. :))

Comment: My upper limit was wrong. Fixed. I also changed the variable of integration for clarity.

Comment: Great :). You might want to put 'squared' on top of the term in the numerator of the exponential function, if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks. I am typo-prone, and find seeing them a little difficult ($10$ inch low quality monitor, and less than perfect eyes).